# How to create SqlParameterCollection with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create a `SqlParameterCollection`, but gives error while adding some `SqlParameter` in `sp.Add()` method.

Please help me how to add parameter and how to pass it to my another function where I declare a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
SqlParameterCollection sp = null;                    
sp.Add(new SqlParameter("@CmpyCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = CV.Global.CMPYCODE;
sp.Add(new SqlParameter("@Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = codeName;
sp.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisplayCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = codeName + "-";
sp.Add(new SqlParameter("@TotalDigit", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = CV.Global.PARAMTOTALDIGIT;
insertData("<Sp Name>", sp);
```

My another function  is insertData(...)

```
internal static int insertData(string spName, SqlParameterCollection sp)
{
        int retObj = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CV.Global.CONSTRING))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (sp.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter param in sp)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }

                retObj = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ev) 
            { 
                Util.Log(ev); 
                throw; 
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ev) { Util.Log(ev); throw; }
            }
        }
        return retObj;
    }
```

I am trying to create a `SqlParameterCollection` and passed it to the `insertData` function. But it throws an error while I am calling `sp.Add()` method in my first function.

The error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: try to use sqlcommand and Parameters.AddWithValue

Comment: You never tell us what error you get, how do you expect us to help if you don't say exactly what happened.

Comment: it gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You cannot use any variable like `SqlParameterCollection` (a reference object) without a call to its constructor (new), but the `SqlParameterCollection` is an object that cannot be initialized directly with a new. It has no public constructor and can be retrieved only from the property of an existant `SqlCommand`.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
 SqlParameterCollection sp = cmd.Parameters;
```

I suggest to change your `InsertData` method to accept a `List<SqlParameter>` and let it handle the adding of the parameters to the `SqlCommand` that executes the command text

```
List<SqlParameter> sp = new List<SqlParameter>()
{
    new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@CmpyCode", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value= CV.Global.CMPYCODE},
    new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@Code", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = codeName},
    new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@DisplayCode", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = codeName + "-"},
    new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@TotalDigit", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = CV.Global.PARAMTOTALDIGIT}
};
insertData(CV.Sps.SP_INSERT_PARAM_TABLE, sp);
```

and `insertData` simply receives an optional list of SqlParameter and add them to the internal `SqlCommand` parameter collection if needed

```
internal static int insertData(string spName, List<SqlParameter> sp = null)
{
    ....
    if(sp != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sp.ToArray());
    ....
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `foreach` you can also just do `cmp.Parameters.AddRange(parameterPassed.ToArray())` this works very well with a `params SqlParameter[] parametersPassed` parameter in your function.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, just busy fixing something on the parameter list initialization

Comment: @Steve         It gives error because i want to add SqlParameter with `SqlDbType` and `Value` both, your code is allow only `("@ParameterName") and (object value) ` but i want to mention a `SqlDbType` also

Comment: I'm using `kudvenkat's` tutorial for logging exceptions to database which only works for one SqlParameter. I'd like to integrate your list solution.
In my example, we set the SqlParamter like so:
                `SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@exceptionMessage", log);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);`

How can I change this SqlParameter format to fit your `new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@CmpyCode", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value= CV.Global.CMPYCODE}` format? I'd like to exclude everything but the `@exceptionMessage` if possible..

Comment: @KyleVassella Sorry but I have no reference to this tutorial. I suggest you to post a new question with the details about your current solution, add what you have tried to integrate this answer and probably you will have more people than me to look at your problem

Comment: Thanks Steve, I may. I guess my question more generally is regarding the different syntax when using `new SqlParameter`. Apparently, when you add `new SqlParameter` to a variable, the following is all that's needed:
                `SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@exceptionMessage", log);`
But in your case, without the variable, SqlParameter expects a code block:
`new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@CmpyCode", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value= CV.Global.CMPYCODE}`

I'd like to know generally what `new SqlServer` expects in the parenthesis and in the code block.

Comment: It is just an [object and collection initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) It is not related to the presence or not of a variable to set. The parameter object has many properties and the simple syntax you showed above takes for granted some defaults. Not very wise if you want the best performance

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks Steve. For now I've gotten it to work by keeping what I originally had in the parenthesis and leaving the blocks blank - I'll keep what you said in mind and specify more info in the blocks later. For anyone wanting to see Steve's answer in a working code example, see my question here (and also the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370142/net-log-exceptions-to-db-using-multiple-sqlparameters-and-specify-what-goes-i

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified answer. I use this type of thing for a dynamic SQL query with dynamic parameters. Sometimes you don't need all parameters if you are writing a dynamic sqlquery when determining if a variable has a value.

```
List<SqlParameter> paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", StartDate));
paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", EndDate));

if (TicketID != "" && TicketID != null && TicketID != "undefined")
{
    paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TicketID", TicketID));
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " AND A.TicketID = @TicketID";
}

var Parameters = paramList.ToArray();
List<Report> ReportList = db.Database.SqlQuery<Report>(SQLQuery, Parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: Make sure to convert the list to an array.