# Passing multiple SqlParameter to method

Tags: c#, methods, sqlparameter

In my main form, I have implemented this code..

```
void SampleMethod(string name, string lastName, string database)
{
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter();
        sqlParam.ParameterName = "@name";
        sqlParam.Value = name;
        sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

        SqlParameter sqlParam1 = new SqlParameter();
        sqlParam1.ParameterName = "@lastName";
        sqlParam1.Value = lastName;
        sqlParam1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

        SqlParameter sqlParam2 = new SqlParameter();
        sqlParam2.ParameterName = "@database";
        sqlParam2.Value = database;
        sqlParam2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass(new DBConn(@serverName, tableName, userName, password));
        sampleClass.executeStoredProc(dataGridView1, "sp_sampleStoredProc", sqlParam, sqlParam1, sqlParam2);
}
```

And in my `SampleClass`, I have this kind of method.

```
public DataGridView executeStoredProc(DataGridView dtgrdView, string storedProcName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(storedProcName, sqlconn);
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;

            // Loop through passed parameters
            if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in parameters)
                    sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            sqlDA.Fill(dt);
            dtgrdView.DataSource = dt;
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            sqlconn.Close();
        }

        return dtgrdView;
}
```

What I am trying to do is avoid multiple

```
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter()
```

in my code, I have tried so many solutions for this problem but I didn't get the right answer. I have also tried to research about this but I still couldn't get the right answer.

Please don't mind my naming convention and other codes as I intentionally change many of them :) Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: You can create parameters with `Parameters.Add` yet your code is *explicitly* written to pass individual parameters to `executeStoredProc`. That's a bit self-contradictory. Why do you want to avoid multiple parameters at all?

Comment: Try to create separate class for data access in which you return only the result of SqlDataAdapter(DataTable, DataSet). You can make your Data access layer methods to take parameters SqlCommand in this way you will avoid having multiple Sql parameters. You can check the answer of this question I wrote simple DAL-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145. You can re use it. Also in current format the question is too broad.

Comment: or as an alternative you can use something like Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). You still need to use multiple parameters if your stored procedure or query needs it, but this is nicely abstracted for you...

Comment: @mybirthname you can't "avoid" multiple parameters. If the sproc requires multiple parameters you have to provide them. Your linked answer is unsafe (you aren't using `using`) and can't even pass all the information required by a parameter. A microORM like Dapper would be simpler and safer

Comment: I want to avoid multiple parameters to lesser the line of codes. That's my main reason at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you don't know using is try/catch/finally block. Nothing is unsafe. Aso before downvote a code try to understand it, it will help you in the future

Comment: @SyntaxError you must specify the length of the string parameters, otherwise you'll send `nvarchar(1)` values.

Comment: You can use the Object Collection Initializer syntax to shorten your code but you can't really avoid to create all the parameters needed by the call. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320701/how-to-create-sqlparametercollection-with-multiple-parameters/23320836#23320836

Comment: @mybirthname you don't seem to realize that your code allows for escaped exceptions. There is a reason `using` is used instead of `try/finally`. You can't use it though since you introduce the `GetSqlConnection` method that actually *creates* a connection and assigns it to a command (two independent tasks). You also don't seem to be aware that `AddWithValue` is *not* safe - it can easily infer the wrong type or size

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to your solution, try to use already existing one instead,  using Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

You still need to use multiple parameters if your stored procedure or query needs it, but this is nicely abstracted for you and this will definatelly reduce the amount of code.

```
void SampleMethod(string name, string lastName, string database)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(MY_CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        var resultListOfRows = connection.Query<ReturnObject>(MY_STORED_PROCEDURE, new { 
            name = name,
            lastName = lastName,
            database = database}, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `Query` not `Execute`

Answer (score 1):

Separate your Database logic at one place(put sqladapter, sqlcommand etc at one place), Then encapsulate parameters within your command like mentioned below and you don't need to declare sqlparameter separately, add it inside parameters list.

```
 cmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parameter", value));
```

Take a look at the complete example below

```
    public DataTable ProdTypeSelectAll(string cultureCode)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdToExecute = new SqlCommand();
        cmdToExecute.CommandText = "dbo.[pk_ProdType_SelectAll]";
        cmdToExecute.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable toReturn = new DataTable("ProdType");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdToExecute);
        cmdToExecute.Connection = _mainConnection;
        cmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CultureName", cultureCode));
        _mainConnection.Open();
        adapter.Fill(toReturn);
        return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does but in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [SqlParameter Constructor (String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx). Replace:

```
sampleClass.executeStoredProc(dataGridView1,
        "sp_sampleStoredProc",
        sqlParam,
        sqlParam1,
        sqlParam2);
```

With:

```
sampleClass.executeStoredProc(dataGridView1,
        "sp_sampleStoredProc",
        new SqlParameter("@name", (object)name),
        new SqlParameter("@lastName", (object)lastName),
        new SqlParameter("@database", (object)database));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the easiest option would be to use a microORM like Dapper, and retrieve a strongly-typed collection. Gridviews can bind to anything, including strongly typed collections. All this code could become:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var result= connection.Query<ResultClass>("sp_MySproc", 
                         new { Name= name, LastName= lastName,Database=database},
                         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    return result;
}
```

Even when using raw ADO.NET, you can create a SqlParameter in one line by using the [appropriate constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) . For example, you can create a new `nvarchar(n)` parameter with:

```
var myParam=new SqlParameter("@name",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20);
```

or

```
var myParam=new SqlParameter("@name",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20){Value = name};
```

A better idea though is to create the SqlCommand object just once and reuse it. Once you have an initialized SqlCommand object, you can simply set  a new connection to it and change the parameter values, eg:

```
public void Init()
{
    _loadCustomers = new SqlCommand(...);
    _loadCustomers.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.NVarChar,20);
    ...
}

//In another method :
using(var con=new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
{       
    _loadCustomers.Connection=con;
    _loadCustomers.Parameters["@name"].Value = myNameParam;
    con.Open();
    using(var reader=_load.ExecuteReader())
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing with a SqlDataAdapter, in fact that's how Windows Forms and Data Adapters are meant to be used since .NET 1.0 .

Instead of creating a new one each time you want to fill your grid, create a single one and reuse it by setting the connection and parameters before execution. You can use the [SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to make things a bit cleaner:

```
public void Init()
{
    _loadCustomers = new SqlCommand(...);
    _loadCustomers.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.NVarChar,20);
    ....
    _myGridAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_loadCustomers);
    ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    _myGridAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection=con;
    _myGridAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@name"].Value =....;
    con.Open();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    _myGridAdapter.Fill(dt);
    dtgrdView.DataSource = dt;
    return dtgrdView;
}
```