# .NET - log exceptions to db using multiple SqlParameters and specify what goes in each db column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, exception

I'm following `KudVenkat`'s tutorial for logging exceptions to the database in `.NET`: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/12/logging-exception-to-database-part-75.html

His way is good for storing one thing - an ExceptionMessage string containing Exception Message, Exception Type, Stack Trace, etc - into one column - the `@exceptionMessage` column.

I'm trying to split this full Exception Message up into parts, such as ExceptionType (to the @exceptionType column), exceptionMessage (to the @exceptionMessage column), StackTrace (to the @stackTrace column), etc.

So far, I'm able to pass in multiple `SqlParameters` using:

```
        List<SqlParameter> sp = new List<SqlParameter>() {
            new SqlParameter("@exceptionType", log) { },
            new SqlParameter("@exceptionMessage", log) { }

        };

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sp.ToArray());
```

But I can't seem to split this data out into the columns I desire - the way I'm doing it, I have to call my logger function for each of my SqlParameters **(see my code comments below)**, and they each create a new row with the same message on every column. Rather than `Type` going to Type column and `Message` going to Message column, it creates one row with `Message` inserted into both the Type and Message columns, then another row with `Type` inserted into both the Type and Message columns.

I believe this has to do with the nature of my LogToDB class:

```
public class storedProcedure : ApiController
{
    public static void Log(Exception exception)
    {

        // exception type
        StringBuilder sbExceptionType = new StringBuilder();

        // exception message
        StringBuilder sbExceptionMessage = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            // exception type
            sbExceptionType.Append("Exception Type" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbExceptionType.Append(exception.GetType().Name);
            sbExceptionType.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            // exception message
            sbExceptionMessage.Append("Message" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbExceptionMessage.Append(exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbExceptionMessage.Append("Stack Trace" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbExceptionMessage.Append(exception.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        while (exception != null);

////Calling this twice is a problem. How can I rebuild this to log both into the appropriate column?////
        LogToDB(sbExceptionMessage.ToString());
        LogToDB(sbExceptionType.ToString());
    }

    private static void LogToDB(string log)
    {

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["redacted"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("redacted", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            List<SqlParameter> sp = new List<SqlParameter>() {
                new SqlParameter("@exceptionType", log) { },
                new SqlParameter("@exceptionMessage", log) { }

            };

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sp.ToArray());

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you're passing the same value to both parameters. `log` - change `LogToDB(string log)` to `LogToDB(string exceptionMessage, string exceptionType)` and pass the values accordingly...

Comment: You are correct - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `LogToDb` twice causes inserting 2 rows into the database.

Passing `log` as `@exceptionType` and `@exceptionMessage` parameter values causes same value to be inserted in `Type` and `Message` columns.

Modify `LogToDB` as

```
private static void LogToDB(string exceptionType, string exceptionMessage)
{
   ....
   List<SqlParameter> sp = new List<SqlParameter>() {
            new SqlParameter("@exceptionType", exceptionType) { },
            new SqlParameter("@exceptionMessage", exceptionMessage) { }

        };
   ...

 }
```

And invoke `LogToDB` only **once** (Instead of twice as you do now)

```
LogToDB(sbExceptionType.ToString(), sbExceptionMessage.ToString());
```

Comment: I've never had a quicker reply or a more direct fix - thank you very much, this worked. Glad the fix was relatively simple.